# Spring Jpa Update: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

I try to use handle query for updating table in the `SQL` database.

Code:

```
    @Autowired
    private ProducerRepository producerRepository;

    public void update(Producer producer){

        String name = producer.getProducerName();
        long id = producer.getId();

//        producerRepository.save(producer); //this method works well.
        producerRepository.update(name, id); //handle attempt - throws exeption in this string
    }
```

ProducerRepository:

```
@Repository
    public interface ProducerRepository extends JpaRepository<Producer, Long>{

        @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE producer SET producer_name = :pName WHERE id = :id")
        Producer update(
                @Param("pName") String pName,
                @Param("id") long id
        );
    }
```

All parameters of the `producer` entity are correct and `producerRepository.save(producer)` works well.
(also I out in console `name` and `id` fields - all right)

**So, I can save `producer` in the database, but, when I try to use `update()` method I get the error.**

> Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

---

PS

sql query in the console also works well

```
(UPDATE producer SET producer_name = 'some name' WHERE id = ....)
```

It should be noted that other SQL native queries in repository work correctly. So the spring/hibernate/jdbc settings are correct.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use annotation `@Modifying`.

> This will trigger the query annotated to the method as updating query
>   instead of a selecting one.

From **2.2.6 Modifying queries** https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Answer (score 9):

In case above solution not work  use this

```
@Modifying
    @Transactional 
    @Query(value ="delete from admindata where user_name = :userName AND group_name = :groupName",nativeQuery = true)
    public void deleteadminUser(@Param("userName") String userName,@Param("groupName") String groupName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE producer SET producer_name = :pName WHERE id = :id")
        Producer update(
                @Param("pName") String pName,
                @Param("id") long id
        );
```

your update method is returning Producer Object, the return should be either int or void, since you are returning Producer entity, Spring JPA is thinking that it has to fetch the object instead of updating it, that is the reason it is executing executeQuery, instead of executeUpdate and also you need to @Modifying annotation.